# How does the @ApiOperation annotation work in spring?

Tags: spring, springfox

I want to know hoew does the annotation from spring @ApiOperation(value = "", hidden = true) works to hide information on my swagger page.

1. What class is responsible to load the annotation
2. What does it do with that same values of the annotation.

Where can I find how the annotation works?

Comment: https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `springfox.documentation.spring.web.readers.operation.ApiOperationReader.read(RequestMappingContext)` method orchestrates the scanning of methods annotated with `@ApiOperation` and takes into consideration the `hidden` flag when doing so, you can see it in the sourcecode over at [GitHub](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/09d4a734b64a216bb5c26c0329f3d15b8276c0e4/springfox-spring-web/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/readers/operation/ApiOperationReader.java#L73-L77).

The specific method that scans the annotated methods and populates the context with the information regarding whether such method should be hidden or not can be found [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/09d4a734b64a216bb5c26c0329f3d15b8276c0e4/springfox-swagger-common/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/swagger/readers/operation/OperationHiddenReader.java#L38-L41).

You can keep browsing the source code for more information regarding the implementation, and you can also get more information regarding the `@ApiOperation` annotation over at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations#apioperation.